# Is the collection of open squares with axis parallel to the axes a basis for the euclidean topology?

Tags: general-topology

Hi I was working on a problem concerning euclidean topology. I was doing the following exercise :

[image]

The first statement seemed not to be true because for (i) to be the basis some topology the intersection of any most belong to the basis. As the intersection of any two open squares parallel to the axes is not necessarily a square, possible a rectangle. I assumed it wasn't the basis for any topology.

This however didn't make sense when I looked at (ii) as far as I know the collection of all open discs is a basis for the euclidean topology. But the intersection of two disc is not always a disc. Which would mean it isn't the basis for any topology which left me confused.

Does anyone know where I could be wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

> ... to be the basis some topology the intersection of any must belong to the basis...

That is not correct.

What you might be thinking of is this:

> If $B_1,B_2$ are two elements of a basis and if $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$ then there must be another element $B$ of the basis such that
> $$x \in B \subset B_1 \cap B_2
> $$

For the basis of open squares, if you are given two open squares and a point $x$ in their intersection, I'm sure you can convince yourself that there is an open square containing $x$ and contained in each of the two given squares.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement is that the intersection of any two basis elements must be an element of the topology, not of the basis. So looking at the topology generated by the "squares" basis, you now know it contains all axis-aligned open rectangles (which also means that you can pretend that those were all part of the basis as well: if $B$ generates a topology $T$, and $K$ is a subset of $T$, then $B \cup K$ also generates $T$, although that's a theorem that needs proving.)

Comment: thx that really clears things up! I ll approve when I can.

Comment: Thanks ... but don't forget Lee Mosher's point, either!